# python list module Segmentation fault

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to list all package install on my machine which is running SL7.3(hence the python 2.7.5). I try running the command `help("modules")`, but I got the following error. Can anyone help. Thank you

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Nov  3 2016, 22:05:29)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> help("modules")

Please wait a moment while I gather a list of all available modules...

dm.c: 1693: not running as root returning empty list
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gobject/constants.py:24: Warning: g_boxed_type_register_static: assertion 'g_type_from_name (name) == 0' failed
  import gobject._gobject
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook.py:136: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The matplotlib.delaunay module was deprecated in version 1.4. Use matplotlib.tri.Triangulation instead.
  warnings.warn(message, mplDeprecation, stacklevel=1)
/usr/lib64/python2.7/pkgutil.py:110: FutureWarning: The pandas.rpy module is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. We refer to external packages like rpy2.
See here for a guide on how to port your code to rpy2: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/r_interface.html
  __import__(name)
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: specified class size for type 'PyGtkGenericCellRenderer' is smaller than the parent type's 'GtkCellRenderer' class size
  from gtk import _gtk
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: g_type_get_qdata: assertion 'node != NULL' failed
  from gtk import _gtk
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: You're better off using something like `pip freeze` or just looking at what's in `site-packages`. The command you're using tries to load all modules and if any conflict, it blows up.

Comment: Thanks pip freeze/ list did the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pip list
```

is this help you ?

or use below codes to see

```
import pip

for dist in pip.get_installed_distributions():
    print(dist)
```

Comment: Thanks pip freeze/list did the job.